# Replacing single quote with \'

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi guys this is a silly but small and important one for me.

I have a jQuery that picks up a bit of string that has single quotes and results in not picking them up at all. i.e.

```
data-name='someone's name';
```

The jQuery that picks up the code

```
$('#id').text($(this).data("name"));
```

My guess is jQuery enclosing is `''` rather `""` so the `'` in `someone's name` is closing the hence this results in `someone`

So I was trying to do the following--

```
string name = "someone's name";

//Attempted replace here
<div data-name='<%# Eval("name").ToString().Replace("'","\'") %>'></div>
```

But I'm getting `Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Trivially use double quotes `dataname="xxx"`. To deal with strings that may contain either quotes you need to encode as HTML entities (`HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode()`)

Comment: You need this or something like that: `Server.HTMLEncode Method` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @AlexK. That's it! Please post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivially use double quotes `data-name="someone's name"`

To deal with strings that may contain either quotes you need to encode as HTML entities:

`HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode("someone's name")` yields `someone&#39;s name`

(You need to use outer `"` as the quote for this to work correctly)